# php mysql date extract with distinct

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

in mysql table i have the field 'date' which has the data as

```
2012-08-02 02:33:26
2012-08-02 05:33:26
2012-07-02 06:33:26
2012-06-02 01:33:26 
2012-06-10 09:33:26 
2011-05-10 10:33:26 
2011-04-10 02:33:26
```

like that

i want to get the output as

```
2012-08
2012-07
2012-06
2011-05
2011-04
```

ie get the unique year and month (distinct of year and month of the date field)

I used the following query

```
SELECT  distinct(YEAR(date)) FROM table
```

It returns the year only. i want to get the output as defined above. is there any possibility to get the out put like this. How do i write the select query.

Please help to this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(colName, '%Y-%m')
FROM tableName
```

**[SEE HERE: Date_Format( )](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)**

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m') FROM table
```

you can get full help from here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

suppose you are getting like this from Database:-

```
$row['date']=2012-08-02 02:33:26;
```

then you can use explode function:-

```
$var=explode(" ",$row['date']);
$date=$var[0];//here you will get  2012-08-02

$res=explode("-",$date);
$res1=$res[0];//you will get 2012
$res2=$res[1];//you will get 08
$res3=$res[2];//you will get 02
```

now the final result:-

```
$final=$res1."-".$res2;//you will get 2012-08
```

this is an alternate answer if you don't want to handle this on MySQL end so you can handle this by using PHP concepts.

Comment: here's an easier way to do it your way: date("Y-m", strtotime('2012-08-02 02:33:26'));

Comment: yes BY this way we can get the Date and it reduces some lines of my code.